# MSAL Adding Scope @"offline_access",@"openid" ,@"profile" Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, azure-ad-msal

I'm Try to adding scope @"offline_access",@"openid" ,@"profile" in Below Code But Show Me Error

```
MSALPublicClientApplication *application = [self createClientApplication];
```

[application acquireTokenForScopes:@[@"User.Read", @"Calendars.Read",@"Calendars.ReadWrite",@"Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared",@"Contacts.ReadWrite",@"Contacts.ReadWrite.Shared",@"Tasks.ReadWrite",@"Tasks.ReadWrite.Shared",@"User.Read.All", @"User.ReadBasic.All", @"profile"]
                       completionBlock:^(MSALResult *result, NSError *error)

Showing Error :
MSAL 0.1.1-dev iOS Sim 10.3 [2017-11-13 09:39:50 - 496E2A0F-2D99-4171-96A9-D36ABCB08188] MSALErrorInvalidParameter: {(
    openid,
    profile,
    "offline_access"
)} are reserved scopes and may not be specified in the acquire token call. (-[MSALBaseRequest validateScopeInput:error:]:96)

Answer (score 2):

MSAL automatically includes those 3 scopes (`offline_access`, `openid`, and `profile`) in each request, you don't have to explicitly pass them.